# Different font for all headings in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I would like to set my chapter/section/subsection headings to use a sans-serif font, but keep the serif font for the body text. How can this be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`sectsty` LaTeX package](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/518.htm~mainFrame).

Put this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
```

Comment: Thanks. There's a manual here if anyone's interested: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the titlesec package, which allows greater flexibility of customisation than sectsty.

```
\usepackage[sf]{titlesec}
```

Comment: This is going to remove the numbers from sections and subsections too.

Comment: @MaxN — why do you say that? I don't think that's correct:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf]{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{hello}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

For the people who want to know why this has to be done differently from e.g. normal text. It is because of the distinction between robust commands and fragile commands. Headings do not allow fragile commands, so you have to specifically tell latex it is robust for example.

[This](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=protect) link explains this further, and [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3612) link shows another alternative to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The first possibility that comes to my mind is to use a document class from the KOMA-script package, they have this set up as a default.